# How do I add the SendQuote Action to the Mobile App

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add the Send Quote action from the actions menu in the web app to the mobile app. This is on the sales quote screen (CR304500). I followed the documentation from the Mobile Framework guide, and I was able to add other buttons. The code I'm using for the mobile screen is

```
update screen CR304500 {
    update container "QuoteSummary" {
        add recordAction "SendQuote" {
            behavior = Void
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out because it was in the Actions Folder, I had to enter it as follows.

```
update screen CR304500 {
  update container "QuoteSummary" {
    add recordAction "SendQuoteActionsFolder" {
      behavior = Void
    }
  }
}
```